# ColdFusion function variable name and CfBuilder

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml, coldfusionbuilder

I need to call a function of an object and pass it a variable. Because I need to make multiple  call to function of this object I've tried to make one only handler that invoke the specific function by the form value I pass it. The code works, but CFBuilder show me that there is an error (missing semicolon on the last row). I'm on Railo.

```
local.myReport = seoUtility.init();

local.func = form.action;

local.report = local.myReport[local.func](form.user);
```

So the question is: this code is correct? I could simply ignore the cfbuilder error icon?

Comment: The code is correct for Railo CFML, but that syntax is not supported on CF. Strangely enough, Adobe's ColdFusion Builder only supports Adobe ColdFusion's implementation of CFML.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just found a link that explain well this difference between ACF and Railo. however I think I will just ignore the error of cfbuilder.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/zJUxYbUmwl0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want CFBuilder to nag you about the syntax, you can change to this:

```
local.myReport = seoUtility.init();
local.func = local.myReport[form.action];
local.myReport.func = local.func;
local.report = local.myReport.func(form.user);
```

This sets `local.func` to the instance of `seoUtility` as a reference to the actual function you want to call, preserving its relationship to the parent object. This way the offending `[]()` syntax isn't needed.

However, this only works if `seoUtility.init()` is returning a fresh instance every time, as opposed to a singleton shared by the application, in which case there would be a race condition on all calls to `local.myReport.func()`.

Comment: That's not actually equivalent functionality - you are taking the function out of the object it is in, which potentially changes behaviour (depending on what it does). With CF10 Adobe added the [invoke](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Invoke) function (presumably because they're too lazy to fix it properly), but it'd be pointless making the code uglier if it's only being run on Railo.

Comment: Great catch, @PeterBoughton. Updated my answer to maintain the object-function relationship.